# Checkbox list in a DataGrid Cell edit template

Tags: c#, wpf

I try to check only couple checkbox in a WPF datagrid cell, base on database data.

I created the checkbox list with a list coming from my database, and the list appear when I'm in editing mode on the cell. At the moment, I can only check them all or none.

This is the XAML code from the column where I want to display the checkbox.

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Teacher" Width="100">
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding TeacherName}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{StaticResource TeacherList}">
                <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <CheckBox Content="{Binding}" IsChecked="False"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            </ItemsControl>
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

At the end, I want a DataGrid with classes and a column for the Teacher. I want to be able to associate multiple Teacher to the class. When I enter edit mode on a cell, I want to be able to display all my teacher's name from my Database (so I don't know them and I don't know the quantity) and only check those who are associate with the class from the row i'm on.

To associate the multiple teacher and the class, I have a table in my database with the teacher ID and the class ID.

Thank you in advance.

**UPDATE**
I've acheived something with your help. I've create a "Teacher" class with the name and a boolean 'IsCheck'.

In my object "Class", the field teacher take a List. I create each list for each classes and set IsCheck to appropriate Teacher.

In my XAML I set the source of the checkbox DataTemplate to this teacher list.

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding TEACHERLIST}">
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <CheckBox Content="{Binding NAME}" IsChecked="{Binding ISCHECK}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>
    </DataTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
```

Comment: Bindings to C# properties are case-sensitive. That means that `ISCHECK` and `IsCheck` are totally different. Are you able to determine which spelling you used in your C# class? Also, you can't bind a field, only a property. A property has a `get` and maybe a `set` block; a field does not. Is the code in your latest update working for you?

Answer (score 0):

When you do

```
 <CheckBox Content="{Binding}" IsChecked="False"/>
```

You are not binding IsChecked to anything.
So whatever you do with that checkbox, I won't be persisted to what's bound.

You should make Teacher a class with at least two public properties. String Name and bool Checked.  Give Checked a default value of false. It should also implement inotifypropertychanged.

Change your markup to:

```
 <CheckBox Content="{Binding Name}" IsChecked="{Binding Checked, Mode=TwoWay"/>
```

Once you do that you should be able to check and uncheck each of those teachers and it will be persisted in the Teacher (instance) that checkbox is bound to.

As an aside.

This UI design seems a bit weird.

A more usual sort of a design would have a Listbox of classes. You select one and the selected class is used to drive what you see in another listbox.

That'd give you a separate list of teachers in another listbox.

Comment: Another problem is that he says "I want to be able to associate multiple Teacher to the class", and it looks like he means one class per row. However, there's only one `TeacherList` resource, so once the binding is correct, if you check Mrs. Krabapple in one row, she's checked in all of them. Each row needs to have its own `TeacherList` with its own set of Teacher instances.

Comment: Indeed, good point Ed. You'd want a list of teachers allocated and a list of all teachers and some logic. Allocating multiple teachers to a class seems a bit odd now I think about it.  Been a while since i was at school but i seem to recall just the one teacher at the blackboard.

Comment: I guess there could be a student teacher and a real teacher, or something. I had one class in high school that the art teacher and the music teacher alternated/cooperated on for some reason.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I keep trying stuff. But yeah, it's for outdoor classes, and sometime they have 2 or 3 teacher, in exemple for sea kayak class where 1 teacher can only have 6 students at a time.